# give high priority to slingbox using iptables

Tags: firewall, iptables

I've been trying for several months now to give highest priority to Slingbox through port 5001 without any success.

Many people recommended using htb qdiscs, but the thing is that I don't want to limit the bandwidth to anyone, I just want to prioritize it.

I'm using gentoo linux with latest kernel sources and latest iptables.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTB qdiscs can prioritise traffic - for example you can state that traffic matching pattern A should be given at least 100Kbyte/sec if it needs it and traffic matching pattern B is give at least 50KByte/sec but both take that traffic from a pool of 200Kbyet/sec. That way each could get 200Kbyet/sec if the other is doing nothing, but both are given some guarantee of traffic if both are active (with traffic marked "A") generally getting more.

For this sort of traffic shaping to be effective though, you do need to set the total cap in both directions to a bit less than your maximum throughput.

Answer (score 0):

Iptables, as far as I know, is just a firewall/packet filter. It doesn't support QoS or anything like that. This would be best to implement on your router... If the box running IPtables is the router, it seems like using HTB might be the best route (no pun intended). Or setup your router to do full differentiated services.